Is the existence of continuous first-order partial derivatives necessary for the differentiability of a complex function?
The theorem for the sufficient conditions for differentiability states:
Let the function
$$f(z) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$$
be defined throughout some $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood of a point $z_0 = x_0 +iy_0$, and suppose that

the first-order partial derivtatives of the functions $u$ and $v$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ exist everywhere in the neighbourhood;
those partial derivatives are continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$ and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations
$$u_x = v_y, \ u_y = -v_x$$ at $(x_0, y_0)$.

Then $f^{\prime}(z_0)$ exists, its value being
$$f^{\prime}(z_0) = u_x + iv_x$$
where the right-hand side is to be evaluated at $(x_0, y_0)$.
However, I came across this problem

Show that the function
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} |z|^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right), & z \neq 0 \\ 0, z = 0 \end{cases}$$
is differentiable at $z = 0$ but the partial derivative of $u(x, y)$ is not continuous at $z = 0$.

From the first principle, we have
$$ \begin{align}
f^{\prime}(0) & = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z - 0} \\
              & = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{|z|^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right) - 0}{z - 0}\\
              & = \lim_{z \to 0}\ \bar{z}\sin\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right) \\
              & = \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \left( x \sin \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right) - i\cdot y \sin \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right) \right) \\
              & = 0
\end{align}$$
and so the derivative exists at $z = 0$.
Now if we consider $u(x, y)$, from the defintion of $f(z)$ we have
$$u(x, y) = \begin{cases} (x^2 + y^2)\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right), & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\ 0, (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$
For $(x, y) = (0, 0)$, we will have
$$\begin{align}
u_x(0, 0) & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{u(0 + h, 0) - u(0, 0)}{h - 0} \\
              & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}}\right)}{h}\\
              & = \lim_{h \to 0}\ h\sin\left(\frac{1}{|h|}\right) \\
              & = 0
\end{align}$$
However, for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ we have
$$ \begin{align}
u_x(x, y)     & = (x^2 + y^2)\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right) \left(\frac{-2x}{2}(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{-3}{2}} \right) + 2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)\\
              & = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right) + 2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)
\end{align}$$
Here if we check along a line $y = mx$ we will find that
$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} u_x(x, y)$$
does not exist at $z = 0$ and hence it is discontinuous at $z = 0$.
Does this not contradict the theorem? We obtained the value for the derivative even though the first-order partial derivative is discontinuous. So do we need to check only the Cauchy-Riemann equations to tell whether a function is differentiable or not?

Where do you see a contradiction? Why do you claim that the first-order partial derivative does not exist?

@JoséCarlosSantos In the expression for $u_x$ for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$, if we try to find the limits along the real axis for example, the limit will approach infinity. If we try to find the limit of $u_x$ along the imaginary axis, we get limit $0$. Since we get two different values from two paths, the limit of $u_x$ and hence $u_x$ should not exist at $z = 0$. And since the first-order partial derivative does not exist at $z = 0$, does this not contradict the theorem since we still get the derivative of $f(z)$ at $z = 0$?

I don't know why you talk about those limits. You have$$u_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{u(x,0)-u(0,0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1{|x|}\right)=0.$$So, where is the problem?

@JoséCarlosSantos Okay so what I am trying to say is, in this equation $$u_x(x, y) = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right) + 2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)$$ if we try to find the limit by approaching the origin along the line $y = 0$, we will obtain $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x}{|x|}\cos\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right) + 2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right) = \pm \cos\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)$$ On approaching from the line $x = 0$, the limit is $$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{0}{|y|}\cos\left(\frac{1}{|y|}\right) + 2\times 0 \times \sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right) = 0$$

I made an error in the previous comment when I said it would go to infinity for $y = 0$, however as we can see we don't have the same value for the limit for two different paths, right? This means that a limit for $u_x(x, y)$ is not defined at the origin. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Please tell me why you are interested in the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}u_x(x,y)$. Why is that limit relevant?

@JoséCarlosSantos The problem I was solving explicitly stated that $u(x, y)$ is not continuous at $z = 0$ and that we are supposed to prove $f^{\prime}(0)$ exists even then. I was trying to prove the same. That is why I differentiated $u(x, y)$ and checked the limit at the origin to verify whether it is continuous. That is why I was calculating that limit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The theorem talks, as you say, about a sufficient condition for differentiability. The example shows that they are not necessary.
